# How do I parse a HTTP Response of following format

Tags: android, api, http

I am using the bulk sms api to trigger send an sms to mobile number in and android phone. The format of the bulk sms api is follows

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx/bulksms/bulksms?username=fds-xxx&password=xxx&type=0&dlr=1&destination=9422522891,8275004333&source=xxx&message=18%20December
```

The following is the response I can get in android as string using code

```
bytesSent = httpclient.execute(httppost, res);
```

response below

```
1701|919422522891:224c1214-bb95-414d-ba76-77db95370545,1701|918275004333:5e93a439-2644-4455-9f01-f27e6cf0cde6
```

How do I parse this response like key value pairs ?

A little success with following code , but it fails when the regex char is '|'

```
  public String[] split(String regex,String input)
    {
        input = "1701|919422522891:224c1214-bb95-414d-ba76-77db95370545,1701|918275004333:5e93a439-2644-4455-9f01-f27e6cf0cde6";
        regex = "|"; // does not work

        //regex = ":"; // works correct
        String[] soso = Pattern.compile(regex).split(input, input.length());

        for (String s : soso) {
            Log.e("TAG",s.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

for regex char '|'

I get a Log output as single characters string array like {"1","7","0",........}

UPDATE

```
regex = "\\|"  // works fine
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use the [split() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) of String to split the response into different entries.
- Loop through the resulting array
- use split() again to separate keys from values
- store the result in a map, `result[0]` is the key,`result[1]` is the value

if you need to maintain order make sure you use a map that does that, e.g. [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

Comment: the split function gives wrong output when the regex char is '|' but it works when the regex char is ":"